# Paneled tables using tabularx that spans across multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, landscape

I have created a 4 paneled table using tabularx. However, the tables along with table notes make this table really large and therefore I want to landscpae this and span the table across two pages. However, my experiments with lansdcaping have failed miserably and I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}% To set line spacing commands like \doublespacing
\usepackage{graphicx} %helps include \includegraphics
\usepackage{tikz} % To draw tikz pictures
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx} % To create panelled tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{landscape}

    \begin{table}[htbp]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
        \caption{Table Caption Here}
        \label{panel_table}
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{4}{Y}}
                \toprule 
                \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}}\\
                \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here} \\\midrule

                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach One} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach Two} \\ 
                \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 

                &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for One}    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for Two}\\ 
                & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \midrule 
                Ind Variable &  1.1111*** & 1.1111**   & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**  \\
                &  (1.11111) & (1.11111)  & (1.11111) & (1.11111) \\  \midrule
                Observations & 5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 \\ 
              \bottomrule   
            \end{tabularx}
        }
        \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{4}{Y}}
            \toprule 
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Panel B}}\\
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here} \\\midrule

            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach One} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach Two} \\ 
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
            \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 

            &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for One}    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for Two}\\ 
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \midrule 
            Ind Variable &  1.1111*** & 1.1111**   & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**  \\
            &  (1.11111) & (1.11111)  & (1.11111) & (1.11111) \\  \midrule
            Observations & 5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 \\ 
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabularx}
    }

    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{4}{Y}}
        \toprule 

        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Panel C}}\\
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here} \\\midrule

        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach One} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach Two} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 

        &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for One}    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for Two}\\ 
        & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \midrule 
        Ind Variable &  1.1111*** & 1.1111**   & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**  \\
        &  (1.11111) & (1.11111)  & (1.11111) & (1.11111) \\  \midrule
        Observations & 5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}
}

        \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{3}{Y}} \toprule
                \multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel D}\\
                Variables &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Another Dep Variable} \\ 
                & (1) & (2) \\\midrule
                genderquota & 1.1111*** & 1.1111**\\
                & (1.1111) & (1.1111) \\
                Constant & 1.1111*** & 1.1111**\\
                & (1.1111) & (1.1111)  \\\midrule
                Observations & 1,1212 & 1,123123 \\
                R-squared & 0.022 & 0.267 \\  
                 \bottomrule
                \multicolumn{3}{c}{ Standard errors in parentheses are clustered} \\
                \multicolumn{3}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
        \end{tabularx} } 
        \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
            \scriptsize Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum \\
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
''''
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: A `table` environment can not be spread over multiple pages. As far I can see, for your table is not need to be in `landscape` page environment. Also, I see, that you have three small tables, not one long (over few pages). Please, elaborate what is your problem.

Comment: Why do you want to use a laddscape page? Do you want to arrange the four tables in a 2x2 grid? Please clarify the desired output. Aldo don't use resizebox on tables since it will leave you with inconsistent font sizes. If you want your tabularx to be only 0.8\textwidth wide, you can directly use \begin{tabularx} {0.8\textwidth}. However, I don't really see the need for tabularx at all in you case. A simple tabular should do fine.

Comment: I need all 4 small tables as panels one below another within the same table number.The problem of having the 2*2 grid is that the 4th table has fewer columns and visually that can be jarring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are more satisfied with the following layout. In it , I have removed the `resizebox` commands, replaced the `tabularx` environment with regular `tabular`s and slightly reduced the `\arraystretch`. Some adjutments regarding the fourth table might however still be needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}% To set line spacing commands like \doublespacing
\usepackage{graphicx} %helps include \includegraphics
\usepackage{tikz} % To draw tikz pictures
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx} % To create panelled tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{landscape}

    \begin{table}[htbp]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
        \caption{Table Caption Here}
        \label{panel_table}
        \centering
        %\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{r}}
                \toprule 
                \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}}\\
                \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here} \\\midrule

                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach One} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach Two} \\ 
                \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 

                &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for One}    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for Two}\\ 
                & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \midrule 
                Ind Variable &  1.1111*** & 1.1111**   & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**  \\
                &  (1.11111) & (1.11111)  & (1.11111) & (1.11111) \\  \midrule
                Observations & 5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 \\ 
              \bottomrule   
            \end{tabular}\hfill
        %}
        %\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{r}}
            \toprule 
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Panel B}}\\
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here} \\\midrule

            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach One} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach Two} \\ 
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
            \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 

            &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for One}    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for Two}\\ 
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \midrule 
            Ind Variable &  1.1111*** & 1.1111**   & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**  \\
            &  (1.11111) & (1.11111)  & (1.11111) & (1.11111) \\  \midrule
            Observations & 5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 \\ 
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
    %}

    %\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{r}}
        \toprule 

        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Panel C}}\\
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here} \\\midrule

        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach One} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Approach Two} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 

        &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for One}    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Citation for Two}\\ 
        & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\ \midrule 
        Ind Variable &  1.1111*** & 1.1111**   & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**  \\
        &  (1.11111) & (1.11111)  & (1.11111) & (1.11111) \\  \midrule
        Observations & 5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 & 1,5000 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}\hfill
%}
%
        %\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{r}} \toprule
                \multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel D}\\
                Variables &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Another Dep Variable} \\ 
                & (1) & (2) \\\midrule
                genderquota & 1.1111*** & 1.1111**\\
                & (1.1111) & (1.1111) \\
                Constant & 1.1111*** & 1.1111**\\
                & (1.1111) & (1.1111)  \\\midrule
                Observations & 1,1212 & 1,123123 \\
                R-squared & 0.022 & 0.267 \\  
                 \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}% } 

        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
        Standard errors in parentheses are clustered 

        *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1

            \scriptsize Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum \\
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, i tried the grid and couldn't get the 4th table to match the others in terms of the look and hence tried one below another.

Comment: I added tabularx for panel d to match the dimensions of the other 3 panels, and removed landscape. The table looks exactly as i wished! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need to have landscape table nor to use `tabularx` (`xltabular` or `ltablex`) table environment. I also would use `S` columns type from the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[%showframe,
            margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{setspace}% To set line spacing commands like \doublespacing
\usepackage{caption} %helps include \includegraphics
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable} % To create panelled tables
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

%\doublespacing

\begin{document}
%        \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
{
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
         round-integer-to-decimal,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=3,
         table-format=2.3,
         table-space-text-post=***}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
%\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{l *{4}{S} }
\caption{Table Caption Here}
\label{panel_table}                                                 \\
    \toprule
    &   \mcc[2]{Approach One}       &   \mcc[2]{Approach Two}       \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &  \mcc[2]{Citation for One}    &   \mcc[2]{Citation for Two}   \\
    & {(1)}            & {(2)}      & {(3)}         & {(4)}         \\ 
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Table Caption Here (Cont.)}                              \\
    \toprule
    &   \mcc[2]{Approach One}       &   \mcc[2]{Approach Two}       \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &  \mcc[2]{Citation for One}    &   \mcc[2]{Citation for Two}   \\
    & {(1)}            & {(2)}      & {(3)}         & {(4)}         \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}} \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
% table body
\mcc[5]{\textbf{Panel A}}                                           \\
\mcc[5]{\textbf{Dep. Var:} \textit{Some Dep Variable Here}}         \\
    \midrule
Ind Variable 
    &  1.1111***    &  1.1111**     &  1.1111** & 1.1111**          \\
    & (1.11111)     & (1.11111)     & (1.11111) & (1.11111)         \\  
    \midrule
Observations 
    & {5,000}       & {1,5000}      & {1,5000}  & {1,5000}          \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\mcc[5]{\textbf{Panel B}}                                           \\
\mcc[5]{\textit{Dep. Var: } Some Dep Variable Here}                 \\
    \midrule
Ind Variable
    &  1.1111***    &  1.1111**     &  1.1111** &  1.1111**         \\
    & (1.11111)     & (1.11111)     & (1.11111) & (1.11111)         \\  
    \midrule
Observations
    & {5,000}       & {1,5000}      & {1,5000}  & {1,5000}          \\
    \midrule
Ind Variable 
    &  1.1111***    &  1.1111**     & 1.1111**  & 1.1111**          \\
    & (1.11111)     & (1.11111)     & (1.11111) & (1.11111)         \\  
    \midrule
Observations 
    & 5,000         & 1,5000        & 1,5000    & 1,5000            \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\mcc[5]{\textbf{Panel D}}                                           \\
    \midrule
genderquota 
    & 1.1111***     & 1.1111**      &           &                   \\
    & (1.1111)      & (1.1111)      &           &                   \\
Constant 
    & 1.1111***     & 1.1111**      &           &                   \\
    & (1.1111)      & (1.1111)      &           &                   \\  
    \midrule
Observations 
    & 1,1212        & 1,123123      &           &                   \\
R-squared
    & 0.022         & 0.267         &           &                   \\  
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{ Standard errors in parentheses are clustered}   \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1}           \\
\end{longtable}
}
{    \scriptsize 
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!